# Solve $Ax \approx b$ for A based on multiple noisy (!) samples of x and b

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for a way to solve an equation system $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ for $A$ based on known values for $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{b}$.

I know that this is undetermined for one sample of $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{b}$ because I have 9 unknowns in $A$ and only 3 equations.

But what if I had three different samples of each $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{b}$? Then I'd have something like:

$$ A\vec{x}^{(1)} = \vec{b}^{(1)}\\ 
 A\vec{x}^{(2)} = \vec{b}^{(2)} \\
 A\vec{x}^{(3)} = \vec{b}^{(3)} $$

That way I'd have 9 equations for 9 unknowns and from what I know the system should generally be solvable, is that correct?

What steps do I need to take in order to solve the system for $A$?

### Update 22.1.18:

In theory the vectorization approach should work.

In practice, unfortunately, what I did not consider is that the vectors that I have are noisy and since both vector sets come from different sources the noise in $x$ is different from the noise in $b$. So, unfortunately

$$ Ax^{(1)}-b^{(1)} \neq Ax^{(2)} -b^{(2)} \neq 0 $$

So I have to somehow approximate $A$.

Comment: For most such problems, there are configurations of samples that can cause problems. If your three samples are colinear, for instance, the solution won’t be unique. You should also be prepared to deal with noise in your data. In the colinear case that combined with limited machine precision might be enough to make the system inconsistent.

Comment: I can add more samples, if that helps, until the equation is solvable.

Comment: Adding more samples is only more likely to give you an inconsistent system of equations.

Answer (score 2):

The system $$ \pmatrix{
a_{1,1} &a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
a_{2,1} &a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
a_{3,1} &a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} 
} 
\pmatrix {x^1_1 \\ x^1_2 \\ x^1_3 }
 = \pmatrix {b^1_1 \\ b^1_2 \\ b^1_3 } $$

can be rewritten, [vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) the matrix, as

$$ \pmatrix {
x^1_1 & x^1_2 & x^1_3 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0 &x^1_1 & x^1_2 & x^1_3 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0 &0& 0& 0 &x^1_1 & x^1_2 & x^1_3 \\
} \pmatrix {a_1 \\ a_2\\ a_3\\ a_4\\ a_5\\ a_6\\ a_7\\ a_8 \\ a _9 } =\pmatrix {b^1_1 \\ b^1_2 \\ b^1_3 } $$

or

$$ \pmatrix {
{\bf x^1} & {\bf 0}& {\bf 0}\\
{\bf 0}& {\bf x^1} & {\bf 0}\\
{\bf 0}& {\bf 0}& {\bf x^1} 
} {\bf a} =\pmatrix { {\bf b^1}} $$

Where ${\bf x^1}$ and ${\bf 0}$ are $1 \times 3$, ${\bf a}$  is $9 \times 1$ and ${\bf b^1}$ is $3 \times 1$

Completing it with the other equations we get

$$ \pmatrix {
{\bf x^1} & {\bf 0}& {\bf 0}\\
{\bf 0}& {\bf x^1} & {\bf 0}\\
{\bf 0}& {\bf 0}& {\bf x^1} \\
{\bf x^2} & {\bf 0}& {\bf 0}\\
{\bf 0}& {\bf x^2} & {\bf 0}\\
{\bf 0}& {\bf 0}& {\bf x^2} \\
{\bf x^3} & {\bf 0}& {\bf 0}\\
{\bf 0}& {\bf x^3} & {\bf 0}\\
{\bf 0}& {\bf 0}& {\bf x^3} \\
} {\bf a} = {\bf X} {\bf a} = \pmatrix { {\bf b^1} \\{\bf b^2} \\{\bf b^3} } $$

which we can solve as $   {\bf a} = {\bf X}^{-1} {\bf b}  $, provided ${\bf X}$ is nonsingular.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to look at it: If you use the $x_i$ as basis vectors, then the $b_i$, expressed in that basis, are the columns of $A$, expressed in that basis. Then you "just" need to transform $A$ back to the standard basis.

PS. It's possible you can save a step here calculation-wise, because the $b_i$ are transformed to the new basis first, and then back again as the columns of $A$.